# Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb/base' on BigCommerce 'stencil bundle'

Tags: node.js, eslint, bigcommerce

When I run `stencil bundle` I see the following:

```
  ➜  cornerstone git:(master) ✗ stencil bundle
  Validating theme...
  Running ESLint...
  /Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:402
              throw e;
              ^

  Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb/base'
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/bigcommerce/cornerstone/.eslintrc
      at Object.ModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:75:19)
      at resolve (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:479:33)
      at load (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:496:24)
      at /Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:392:36
      at Array.reduceRight (native)
      at applyExtends (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:363:28)
      at Object.load (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:530:22)
      at loadConfig (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:64:33)
      at getLocalConfig (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:126:23)
      at Config.getConfig (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.0/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:227:22)
```

When I initially ran `npm install` I saw this:

```
  ➜  cornerstone git:(master) npm install
  npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
  npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency phantomjs-prebuilt@>=1.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
  npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
  npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
  npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency eslint@^2.4.0 included from eslint-config-airbnb will no
  npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
  npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
  npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency eslint-plugin-react@^4.2.3 included from eslint-config-airbnb will no
  npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
  npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
  npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
  npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

As per documentation for I tried running `eslint-config-airbnb` and ran this command:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb eslint@^3.19.0 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.0.1 eslint-plugin-import@^2.2.0 eslint-plugin-react@^7.0.1
```

Based on this:

```
  ➜  cornerstone git:(master) ✗ npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies

  { eslint: '^3.19.0',
    'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y': '^5.0.1',
    'eslint-plugin-import': '^2.2.0',
    'eslint-plugin-react': '^7.0.1' }
```

Comment: Reinstall cornerstone for the latest github master. The changed that caused this has been reverted.

Comment: I just did that and still having an error. Latest npm install shows this: `npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@6.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^4.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.0 requires a peer of phantomjs-prebuilt@>=1.9 but none was installed.`

Comment: @Alyss, any thoughts?

Comment: Reinstall stencil-cli, a new version has been released with the fix

Answer (score 11):

It occurs when you use global `eslint` package and non-global `eslint-config-airbnb`.

You can solve it by `npm install eslint --save-dev` && `npm uninstall eslint -g`

Comment: This answer is right, but if you see that this is not uninstalling eslint, you could follow this instructions in order to uninstall it:

1. Run npm uninstall -g ionic
2. Go to the location /usr/local/bin/
3. Delete the eslint file
4. Close the terminal and open a new one, or start a new shell
5. Run npm uninstall -g ionic
6. Now run eslint -v

You are going to see that its not anymore

Answer (score 0):

Everyone that has errors like this, just add the folder to your npm i command. It fixed all of my issues. So for example.

you have your project in this folder:
`c:/user/tim/web/website/`

Than you cd into your folder (website). You should be in the folder your packet.json is in.
Than you can do `npm i /user/tim/web/website/`

I'm sure you could also link your paths so that npm also looks at the right (local) location for your packages instead of globally.